# What is the file extension of the file that is loaded in a Xilinx FPGA?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, xilinx

I wonder what is the file extension that described the functionality of my design and is the file that is loaded in a Virtex 4 FPGA to get the behavior of my VHDL design.
Thank you.

Comment: btw, this would be a perfect question for this area 51 proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20632/programmable-logic-and-fpga-design?referrer=YmxhQ2OJUo-FAaI1gMp5oQ2 consider supporting it

Comment: But, could you take content from this site to that FPGA site?

Comment: the proposal needs more committers in order to be created, to eventually become just like an stack exchange site, but with many FPGA experts. Currently it's only at the commit phase, so questions cannot be asked there yet.

Comment: @saar drimer: I´ve joined to your proposal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This file is commonly called a "bitstream". Xilinx devices' bitstreams have the extension '.bit' and are generated by a program called 'bitgen'. '.bit' files are binaries and those are generated by default; if you want the ASCII representation of the bitstream, run

```
bitgen -b <your design>.ncd
```

and then a '.rbt' file will be generated in addition to the '.bit' file.

For further information about generating Xilinx bistreams, see Chapter 15 in this user guide for ISE version 12.4:

http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx12_4/devref.pdf

For more information about Virtex 4 bistreams specifically, see the configuration guide for that device:

http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug071.pdf